# Reseting number java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

So i got problem in java to determine who the last kid who got the candy, n is how many children, m is how many candy, and s is the number of kid who got the first candy.
so basically if n =4, m=6, and s =2 the answer is 3, because all started from 2(number of kid who got the first candy)->3->4 and restart to 1->2->3 and 3 is the last kid who got the candy.
the code run perfectly but i encounter bug at n = 3333, m =3333, and s = 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int s = in.nextInt();
        int total = m%n;
        int jaw = total+s-1;
            System.out.print(jaw);
        
        
}
```

Comment: What answer do you get, and what answer do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the "bug" you're mentioning is that `jaw` is 0, right? That's because `3333%3333` will be 0 and thus `0 + s - 1` will be `0` as well (0+1-1 = 0).

You're on the right track, i.e. `m % n` would tell you how many pieces of candy are left after everyone got a fair/equal share.

Now you just distribute the "rest" (`total`) which means you "add" it to "first child" (`s`). Let's say this is `c = s + total`, so `c` is the last child that got anything. You subtract -1 because if you add anything the "cursor" advances to the next child and thus you want to track back.

However, what if you didn't have anything to distribute? Then the last child that got anything was the one *before* the first, which in case of 4 children and starting at 1 would be the 4th. Your calculation results in 0 which basically would express this.

Another problem you might face with your code is that if you start at the last child (say 4) and have 2 pieces of candy to distribute, then you'd get the "5th" child instead of the "1st" to be the last to get something: `2 + 4 - 1 = 5`.

So how do you solve that?

- Add `jaw %= n` to handle the "overflow" (if you start at the last child and distributed 2 more pieces of candy, the first would get it)
- Check if `jaw == 0` in which case the solution would be `jaw = n` (the last child got the last candy)

Comment: i encounter bug again if n= 27 m =26, and s =2, the answer should be 27, but the output is 26

Comment: Well, `26 % 27 = 26`, `26 + 2 - 1 = 27` and `27 % 27 = 0` which means the last child got a candy last (this is the second bullet point I mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you arrive at person 0 , who does not exist.
3333%3333 = 0
then 0 + 1 - 1 = 0
As we are in a loop 0 is the last person of the previous turn ie person number m.
We solve this by saying that, if the result is zero we return m.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class sweets {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int s = in.nextInt();
        int total = m%n;
        int jaw = total+s-1;
        if(jaw == 0){
                jaw = m;
                }
        System.out.print(jaw);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider whenever m%n==0.

In that case jaw= n-s+1;

Just need to add an if statement to include it.